# replace missing data in multiple column by different specific value

Tags: r, replace, na, missing-data

I have a huge data frame with several missing value that I need to replace as follow:

| Cycle A | Cycle B | Cycle C | ..... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| na | na | na |  |
| na | na | na |  |
| na | na | na |  |
| -1 | na | 0 |  |
| -1 | -2 | 0 |  |
| na | -2 | na |  |
| na | na | na |  |
| na | na | 1 |  |
| 0 | -1 | 1 |  |
| 0 | -1 | na |  |
| na | na | na |  |
| na | na | na |  |
| na | 0 | 2 |  |
| 1 | 0 | 2 |  |
| 1 | na | na |  |
| na | na | na |  |

For each column I need to replace the NA's by the next number that appears, to have something like that:

| Cycle A | Cycle B | Cycle C | ..... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -1 | -2 | 0 |  |
| -1 | -2 | 0 |  |
| -1 | -2 | 0 |  |
| -1 | -2 | 0 |  |
| -1 | -2 | 0 |  |
| 0 | -2 | 1 |  |
| 0 | -1 | 1 |  |
| 0 | -1 | 1 |  |
| 0 | -1 | 1 |  |
| 0 | -1 | 2 |  |
| 1 | 0 | 2 |  |
| 1 | 0 | 2 |  |
| 1 | 0 | 2 |  |
| 1 | 0 | 2 |  |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |  |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |  |

Any idea how to do that?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify what the general rule would be - it looks like NAs are replaced with the first non-missing value underneath. But what about the NAs at the end of the column - how do we know that the last NA in the first column is meant to be replaced with "2", for example?

Comment: Try `tidyr::fill(df, starts_with("Cycle"), .direction = "up")`

Comment: the rule would be, after the last non-missing value, implement  the value by "+1"

Answer (score 2):

Assume you want to perform replacement in all columns that `starts_with` Cycle.

The first `fill` function replaces `NA` with the next row values. The `mutate` function replaces `NA` in the last row to be last non-NA value + 1.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  fill(starts_with("Cycle"), .direction = "up") %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("Cycle"), ~ replace_na(.x, last(.x[!is.na(.x)]) + 1)))

   CycleA CycleB CycleC
1      -1     -2      0
2      -1     -2      0
3      -1     -2      0
4      -1     -2      0
5      -1     -2      0
6       0     -2      1
7       0     -1      1
8       0     -1      1
9       0     -1      1
10      0     -1      2
11      1      0      2
12      1      0      2
13      1      0      2
14      1      0      2
15      1      1      3
16      2      1      3
```

Comment: I have one problem with that (my fault I did not mention it) in between each column I have other columns (character and numeric), so I get an error message while tryin this code: Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = across(everything(), ~replace_na(.x, last(.x[!is.na(.x)]) + 1))`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Problem while computing column `NOTH`.
Caused by error in `last(NOTH[!is.na(NOTH)]) + 1`:
! non-numeric argument to binary operator         Is there a way to run that only for the columns that starts with "Cycle" for instance?

Comment: @Virginie See my update. This assumes you want to perform replacement in all columns that starts with `Cycle`

Comment: @Virginie You can click on the little tick mark on the left hand side of your favourite answer to accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

First, convert `"na"` to `NA` and `type.covert` for numeric values.

```
dat <- replace(dat, dat== 'na', NA) |> type.convert(as.is=TRUE)
```

Next, I might be wrong, are you looking for this underlying structure?

```
f <- \(x) {
  rp <- cumsum(c(0, diff(!is.na(x))) > 0) + min(x, na.rm=TRUE)
  nas <- is.na(x)
  x[nas] <- rp[nas]
  x
}

cols <- c("CycleA", "CycleB", "CycleC")  ## select columns

dat[cols] <- lapply(dat[cols], f)
dat
#    CycleA CycleB CycleC
# 1      -1     -2      0
# 2      -1     -2      0
# 3      -1     -2      0
# 4      -1     -2      0
# 5      -1     -2      0
# 6       0     -2      1
# 7       0     -1      1
# 8       0     -1      1
# 9       0     -1      1
# 10      0     -1      2
# 11      1      0      2
# 12      1      0      2
# 13      1      0      2
# 14      1      0      2
# 15      1      1      3
# 16      2      1      3
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(CycleA = c("na", "na", "na", "-1", "-1", "na", 
"na", "na", "0", "0", "na", "na", "na", "1", "1", "na"), CycleB = c("na", 
"na", "na", "na", "-2", "-2", "na", "na", "-1", "-1", "na", "na", 
"0", "0", "na", "na"), CycleC = c("na", "na", "na", "0", "0", 
"na", "na", "1", "1", "na", "na", "na", "2", "2", "na", "na")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```